# Is MySQL fractional second support necessary when using PaperTrail?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

The [`CreateVersions` migration](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/445c93f317af87aec0f13fc78f4a2e3efd26bb5b/lib/generators/paper_trail/templates/create_versions.rb#L26) provided by [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) says

> MySQL users should manually add fractional seconds precision to this migration

And also says that the experimental association tracking feature requires fractional seconds in [the README](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/329e22493c74dd6f2c37edcf7eadb5d9ff14f1dd/README.md#4b1-known-issues).

Is this actually necessary for the library to function properly? I would assume that if fractional seconds were not permitted, that data would simply be lost and the timestamp would have the nearest whole second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PT currently depends on fractional seconds precision (in all tables, not just `versions`) for two things, that I know of:

1. the `touch_with_version` method
2. the experimental association tracking feature

I'm pretty sure we can rewrite `touch_with_version` to remove this dependency, not at all sure about association tracking.

Thankfully, modern versions of MySQL now come with fractional seconds precision, so you can just upgrade! (trollface)

Comment: or just use postgres (double trollface)